# How to activate Net Reactor with the license file by using command line

Tags: .net, cmd, github-actions, license-key, net-reactor

I did purchase the license of the .Net Reactor, but I couldn't find any documentation about how to activate the .Net Reactor to Full version by using command line.

1. The reason why I need to using command line to activate is because I try to implement the process into GitHub Actions.

Steps: Install .Net Reactor > Build Solution > Obfuscation

2. Another reason is MacOS does not have UI, everything is using terminal to execute the obfuscation process.

I'm using latest version, .Net Reactor 6.9.0.0 on Win and MacOs. I did try using option
`-licensed` and `-staticlicensefilename license.license`
But I dun have time to wait 14 days later to check the obfuscated dlls was expired or not.
Or anyone know how to check the obfuscated dlls expiration?

Thanks

Im expecting someone who used .Net Reactor able to give some guideline on how to activate the .Net Reactor Full version on Window and MacOS by using command line.

Comment: Can you show me how to use .Net Reactor 6.9.0.0 command line on Mac OS, there is not examples on .Net reactor site.

Answer (score 1):

### Background (with cautionary note!)

Unfortunately, the official way to activate .NET Reactor on Linux / macOS is not documented and their support hasn't responded to email requests for the details. However, in the (unstaffed) [support channel](https://groups.google.com/g/net-reactor-support/c/24fFBi_Q03o/m/yvnFrprAi7EJ) on google groups a user mentioned [a website](https://www.reactoractivation.com) that can be used for activation.

**CAUTION:** From looking at the WHOIS information it *appears* that this site is legit but it would be great if [Eziriz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12720992/eziriz) would chime in and confirm.

Here is screenshot of the activation site at the time of writing:

[image: .NET Reactor License Activation website screenshot]

---

### Instructions

1. Visit the [.NET Reactor download page](https://www.eziriz.com/reactor_download.htm) to download the Linux or macOS binary.
2. Unzip the binary.
3. Make it executable, e.g. `chmod +x dotNET_Reactor`
4. Obtain the **Hardware ID** (see section **Finding the Hardware ID** below for instructions).
5. Visit the [activation site](https://www.reactoractivation.com). You will need to supply:

   a. An **email address** for the license to be sent to.

   b. Your **main license file**, likely named `license.license`.

   c. The **Hardware ID** of the Linux / macOS machine.
6. You will very promptly be emailed a hardware specific license file, likely named `license.v3lic`.
7. If you place this in the same directory as the `dotNET_Reactor`
   executable, it will now run in full mode.
8. You can verify this by running `./dotNET_Reactor -licensed; echo $?` and checking that `101` is not printed.

---

### Finding the Hardware ID

To find the Hardware ID of your Linux/macOS machine, run the executable without any arguments:

```
me@mymachine ~ % ./dotNET_Reactor
     _  _  ___  _____    ___  ___    _     ___  _____   ___   ___
    | \| || __||_   _|  | _ \| __|  /_\   / __||_   _| / _ \ | _ \
  _ | .` || _|   | |    |   /| _|  / _ \ | (__   | |  | (_) ||   /
 (_)|_|\_||___|  |_|    |_|_\|___|/_/ \_\ \___|  |_|   \___/ |_|_\
                                          v6.9.0.0 - Demo Version

Hardware ID: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
```

Comment: I also own this product and I'm quite concerned that I don't get any answers to support requests too. Are they still in business?

Comment: We have had responses to _some_ support requests but not others. Seems this approach has been going on for [some time....](https://groups.google.com/g/net-reactor-users/c/LxxybIAaNvw) Not ideal!

Answer (score 0):

It remains to be seen if GitHub Action can emulate the right environment to support .Net Reactor.

That tool is normally used (and activated) in an Azure pipeline, like [`Eziriz.reactor-tool-task`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Eziriz.reactor-tool-task) ([changelog](https://www.eziriz.com/reactor_history.htm))

> As .NET Reactor is Windows based a Windows build agent must be used. You can define a Windows agent in your pipelines YAML file the following way:
>
> [image: https://eziriz.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/eziriz/reactor-tool-task/0.2.3/1563281982975/images/setup.png]

---

However, the [OP sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20720680/sam) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74726440/how-to-activate-net-reactor-with-the-license-file-by-using-command-line/74726554?noredirect=1#comment132022353_74726554):

> The eziriz support did reply my email.
> Unfortunately, **they not support GitHub Actions yet**, but it is their plan now.

Comment: thanks for help.
finally the eziriz support did reply my email.
unfortunately, they not support github action yet but it is their plan now.

Comment: @sam Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Is there any update here? Is it possibile now use.net reactor with Github Action?